# Decompress a zip file with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, zip

I made a game in Swift but I need to download .zip files on my website, and use the content (images) in game.
Actually, I download the .zip file and store it in documents, and I need to unzip the file into the same documents folder.

I tried marmelroy's Zip, iOS 9 Compression module and tidwall's DeflateSwift but none of these worked. It could be good if it was compatible with iOS 8.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I recently released a Swift native framework that allows you to create, read and update ZIP archive files: [ZIP Foundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation).
It internally uses [libcompression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compression/data_compression) for great compression performance.

Unzipping a file is basically just one line:

```
try fileManager.unzipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
```

A full example with some context would look like this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
var sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
sourceURL.appendPathComponent("archive.zip")
var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
destinationURL.appendPathComponent("directory")
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    try fileManager.unzipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
} catch {
    print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
}
```

The [README on GitHub](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) contains more information. All public methods also have full documentation available via Xcode Quick Help.

I also wrote a blog post about the performance characteristics [here](https://thomas.zoechling.me/journal/2017/07/ZIPFoundation.html).

Comment: both try lines give this error: Ambiguous reference to member 'fileManager(_:shouldProceedAfterError:)'

Comment: how can I do in memory?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089278/how-can-i-get-zip-from-data-object-and-unzip-first-entry-file-inside-it

Comment: This is currently in development. A PR that supports in-memory processing of archives has been submitted, but it currently has problems with in-memory writing. Reading works already https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/pull/78

Comment: As of December 2020 method `unzipItem()` appears to be unavailable

Comment: It is available and works just fine: https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation/blob/development/Sources/ZIPFoundation/FileManager%2BZIP.swift#L92 Can you post code or your project setup. Maybe I can help.

Comment: **5+ years later, ZIPFoundation is the only way to go**, it's one of the very best SPMs.  Tap "Add Packages" and paste  github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation.git ,  job is done. Bravo, ZIPFoundation!

Answer (score 4):

I just find the following library called [Minizip](https://github.com/dexman/Minizip). Try it

You can use [Zip framework](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) to unZip your file using `Swift`. Simply written in `Swift`

Sample Code

```
do {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("file", withExtension: "zip")!
    let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) // Unzip
    let zipFilePath = try Zip.quickZipFiles([filePath], fileName: "archive") // Zip
}
catch {
  print("Something went wrong")
}
```

If not works for minizip, you can go with [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive), its not written in swift but in Objective-C

Comment: Yes it was the first I tried, it could not find the minizip module when I tried

Comment: You can use ZipArchive then, currently no other framework available as far as I Know

Comment: With SSZipArchive, it can't find the class with same name.

Comment: Try the first one, [MiniZip](https://github.com/dexman/Minizip) I've updated my answer

Comment: If I drag & drop the minizip and vendor folder in my project, it cannot find the Minizip module in my Swift code. I haven't Carthage.

Comment: How to get file from `Data` object instead of file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089278/how-can-i-get-zip-from-data-object-and-unzip-first-entry-file-inside-it

Answer (score 0):

I got it work with SSZipArchive and a bridging header:

1. Drag & drop the SSZipArchive directory in your project
2. Create a {PROJECT-MODULE-NAME}-Bridging-Header.h file with the line ***import "SSZipArchive.h"***
3. In Build Settings, drag the bridging header in Swift Compiler - Code generation -> Objective-C Bridging Header.
4. Use SSZipArchive in your Swift code.

Comment: 5. Add libz to your target after receiving a bunch of linker errors from the 4 steps above.

Answer (score -1):

**This code downloads file to document directory and unzips the zip file**

***Don't forget to install ZIPFoundation***

```
import ZIPFoundation

    func downloadAndUnzip(from urlString: String, toFolder folderName: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let folderURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
    let fileURL = folderURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    
    do { //Creates folder.
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not create directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { (tempLocalURL, response, error) in
        guard let tempLocalURL = tempLocalURL, error == nil else { return }
        
        do { //Moves data to created folder.
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempLocalURL, to: fileURL)
            debugPrint("ZIP File saved to: \(fileURL.path)")
            do { //Try to unzip the file.
                try FileManager.default.unzipItem(at: fileURL, to: folderURL)
                do { //Try to delete zip file.
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURL)
                    debugPrint("ZIP file deleted at:", fileURL)
                } catch {
                    debugPrint("Could not delete ZIP file with error: \(error.localizedDescription)", fileURL)
                }
                debugPrint("Unzip completed!", fileURL)
            } catch {
                debugPrint("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error:\(error)")
            }
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Could not move item: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### It's nowadays completely trivial with the excellent ZIPFoundation SPM

1. Tap "Add Packages" and paste  `github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation.git`
2. `FileManager().unzipItem(at: fromUrl, to: untoUrl)`.

That's all there is to it.

You're done.

Have a beer.

Here's a full example of other typical code you'd use with it:

```
let fromUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourZipFile", withExtension: "zip")!
let untoUrl = FileManager().temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("temp")

do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: untoUrl)
    try FileManager().createDirectory(at: untoUrl, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    try FileManager().unzipItem(at: fromUrl, to: untoUrl, skipCRC32: true)
}
catch { print(error) }

do {
    let items = try FileManager.default
        .contentsOfDirectory(at: untoUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        .sorted{ $0.lastPathComponent < $1.lastPathComponent }
    
    for item in items { print(item.path) }
    blah = items.compactMap{ blah($0) }
}
catch { print(error) }
```

(Note the unrelated handy tip, remove/empty your temp directory each time, or you'll be leaving stuff in it from other runs!)

Answer (score -2):

**Important: Requires Third Party Library**

Using this [library](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) you can use this line:

```
let unzipDirectory= try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) //to unZip your folder.
```

If you want more help , check the repository.

Comment: This is related to using a third-party library, if you are not using it, this code will generate compile time error. I recommend to suggest what's the used library.