# How to unzip data downloaded by ftp in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, zip, unzip

I`m trying to unzip data downloaded on a ftp server. I don't found any issue.

```
ftpData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlrequest, returning: &response)
let data : NSData = ftpData! as NSData
let files = hexStringtoAscii(data.description)
```

when I print 'files' I got the zipped content of what I want.

Could anyone help me to get the 'files' content unzipped

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompress a zip file with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202769/decompress-a-zip-file-with-swift)

Comment: that's not really what I am looking for because I am trying to decode a data which is zip encoded. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip.

```
do {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "zip")!
    let unzipDirectory = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(filePath) // Unzip
    let zipFilePath = try Zip.quickZipFiles([filePath], fileName: "archive") // Zip
}
catch {
  print("Something went wrong")
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to unzip a file but 'files' which is a string, is there an issue to unzip 'files'in an other variable